# Insert form data into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Hi Guys I am having a problem that when adding form data into a database. For some reason the data is not inserted. here is my code:

```
<?php include_once 'secure/connect.php'; ?>
<?php 
$name = "Your Name";
$email = "Your Best Email";
$msg_to_user = "";
if ($_POST['name'] != ""){
    //Be sure to filter this data to deter SQL injection
    $name =  $_POST['name'];
    $name = stripslashes($name);
    $name = strip_tags($name);

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $email = strip_tags($email);

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE email='$email'");
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if(!$email){
        $msg_to_user = '<h4><font color="FF0000">Please Type an email address ' . $name . '</font></h4>';
    } else if ($numRows > 0) {
        $msg_to_user = '<h4><font color="FF0000">' . $email . ' is already in our system</font></h4>';
    } else {
        $sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO newsletter (name, email, dateTime) VALUES ('$name', '$email', now())") or die (mysql_error());
        $msg_to_user = '<h4><font color="0066FF">Thanks' . $name . ', You have been added successfully</font></h4>';
        $name = "";
        $email = "";
    }
}
?>
```

And my html form looks like this:

```
<div class="topForm">
<H3 style="text-align:center">SIGN UP FOR OUR NEWSLETTER</H3>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/><br/>
<input name="mySubmitBtn" type="submit"  value="SUBMIT">
<?php echo $msg_to_user; ?>
</form>
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance all
Phillip

This is what I have now and nothing is still working...

```
<?php 
$name = "Your Name";
$email = "Your Best Email";
$msg_to_user = "";
if ($_POST['name'] != ""){

    include_once 'secure/connect.php';

    //Be sure to filter this data to deter SQL injection
    $name =  $_POST['name'];
    $name = stripslashes($name);
    $name = strip_tags($name);

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $email = strip_tags($email);

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE email='$email'");
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if(!$email){
        $msg_to_user = '<h4><font color="FF0000">Please Type an email address ' . $name . '</font></h4>';
    } else if ($numRows > 0) {
        $msg_to_user = '<h4><font color="FF0000">' . $email . ' is already in our system</font></h4>';
    } else {
        $sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO newsletter (name, email) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."')") or die (mysql_error());
        $msg_to_user = '<h4><font color="0066FF">Thanks' . $name . ', You have been added successfully</font></h4>';
        $name = "";
        $email = "";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: And the error you are getting is ...???

Comment: You should try echoing out the result for `$sql_insert` - You're also sanitizing your data in the wrong order, stripping slashes on your default string and then filling it with user input.

Comment: its not adding anything into the database when I try to add info into my form Salman

Comment: I didnt get to the query before I noticed that you are stripping slashes, and tags, then redefining the variable afterwards, completely invalidating the two lines before it.  You do this for `$email` and `$name`.

Comment: First check if connection is established ?

Comment: @Jaimie Just tried that and nothing comes up have added <?php echo $sql_insert; ?> just above $msg_to_user in the form and nothing happens

Comment: @Nirav the connection is establised I tested hat befor i built this application

Comment: @NappingRabbit how should I filter them?

Comment: i didn't find useful of stripping slash and tag the variable and after that assigning the values from $_POST.

Comment: you can strip slashes if you like, but you should do it after you define the variable.  You redefine the variable in the code you sent, after stripping, to the original posted value.  IFF you are using mysql, and not mysqli or pdo, you can still use `mysql_real_escape_string` http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

without regard to other errors or inconsistencies.  also let me note that you should use mysqli or pdo.  but php uses `time()`

```
$sql_insert = mysql_query("
                           INSERT INTO newsletter 
                           (name, email, dateTime) 
                           VALUES 
                           ('$name', '$email', ".time().")
                         ");
```

or if you want a date time instead of the timestamp you can use the `date()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `now()` from your code. And Use Following code.

```
$time = time()  ;
$sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO newsletter (name, email, dateTime) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$time."' )") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: I got rid of the whole dateTime thing as I dont really need it anyway but it's still not working for some reason! Have left an edit above.  Thanks for your help all

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you are connected to the database ! see what `echo mysql_error();` says
2. if a form was submitted, catch the values, and then sanitize
3. insert query

ps: see what the following do:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) ...

echo mysql_insert_id();

time() not now()
```

see the `id` of the new data inserted

your code, should work, if you follow these steps, and if you are connected to the database